# PHP preg_match_all grab info between matches

Tags: php, regex

I can't figure this out. How do I grab the information between the regex matches? 
My issue seems to be that there are newlines in the string. If I compress it to one line per "Title", some of my attempts work.

I want an output that looks like this:

```
 Array
 (
     [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title1#
            [1] => - contenta
            - contentb
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sometitle2# 
            [1] => - contenta
            - contentb
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ABC3#
            [1] => - asdfasdfasdf
            - random stuff
            more
            something
        )
)
```

Here are some of my attempts so far (I even tried some preg_split here), with example the string.

```
<?php
$str = 'Title1#
-contenta
-contentb

Sometitle2# 
-contenta
-contentb
ABC3#
- asdfasdfasdf
- random stuff
more
something';

$re = '/[A-Za-z]{1,10}[0-9]?#\s?(.*\s)/m';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
print_r($matches);

$re = '/([A-Za-z]{1,10}[0-9]?#\s?)/m';
$keywords = preg_split($re, $str,null,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($keywords);

$parts = preg_split('/([A-Za-z]{1,10}[0-9]?#\s?)/m', $str,null,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($parts);
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex in `preg_match_all`:

```
$re = '~(?ms)^([^#\n]+#)\s+(.*?(?=\n+[^#\n]*#\s|\z))~';
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PGpbNm/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?ms)`: Enable MULTILINE and DOTALL modes
- `^`; Line start
- `([^#\n]+#)\s+`: First capture group. Match a line that ends with `#`
- `(.*?(?=\n+[^#\n]*#\s|\z))`: Second capture group. Match 0 or more characters that either have line with # ahead or `\z`.

---

**Cude:**

```
$re = '/(?ms)^([^#\n]+#)\s+(.*?(?=\n+[^#\n]*#\s|\z))/';
$str = 'Title1#
-contenta
-contentb

Sometitle2#
-contenta
-contentb
ABC3#
- asdfasdfasdf
- random stuff
more
something';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```